Flutter - cannot run by cocoapods 1.15.2 with firebase_code package?
When I run pod update on flutter project, I got issue like this:
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.24.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.24.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Any idea for this?

Seems that is ssl issue from cdn.jsdelivr.net. It have reported on github from guys on the world.

seems like an SSL issue with a remote network, you can try with a different network or check the GitHub issues.

Run the below commands:

cd ios
pod repo remove trunk
pod install


You can try these commands below to avoid this issue:

flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios (it will open iOS directory in your flutter Project on terminal)
pod deintegrate
pod install

Note: If issue still face the same issue, try deleting Podfile.lock and run these commands again. Or you may need to check your packages in pubspec.yaml if newer versions are available for the package causing the issue.

KalpeshChavda's answer worked for me like a charm.
Thank you!
